# Is there a way to reset the position of the commit button back in the sidebar in Intellij Idea community?

Tags: intellij-idea, git-commit

I was saving a file when i accidentally moved the commit button and now it is outside the sidebar.
Is there a way to put it back in or reset the position of all the buttons?[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8K13.jpg)

Comment: Does `Window | Restore Default Layout` help?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't quite understand what you mean by "moved the commit button and now it is outside the sidebar", but I took a look at your screenshot.

Assuming that you changed the Commit tool back to its old modal interface, you could easily revert that:

- Go into Settings (`CTRL`+`ALT`+`S` for Windows)
- Navigate to `Version Control` > `Commit`
- Enable the option `Use non-modal commit interface`

[image: Enable this option]

With that option enabled, your commit tools should appear as an item in your left sidebar.